# Locking mysql table in a concurrent function causes an unexpected infinite loop

Tags: python, mysql

I've a function in my code which is as follows:

```py
async def register():
 db = connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='root',database='testing')
 cursor = db.cursor()
 cursor.execute('LOCK TABLES Data WRITE;')     
 cursor.execute('SELECT Total_Reg FROM Data;')
 data = cursor.fetchall()
 reg = data[0][0]
 print(reg)
 if reg >= 30:
  print("CLOSED!")
  return      
 await asyncio.sleep(1)
 cursor.execute('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE Id = 1')
 cursor.execute('COMMIT;')
 print("REGISTERED!")   
 db.close()
```

In case of multiple instances of this `register` function running at the same time, there is an unexpected infinite loop occurs blocking my entire code. Why is that so? Also, if it's a deadlock [I assume] then why my program is not raising any error? Please tell me why is this happening? And what can be done to prevent this issue?

Comment: Why do you lock tables? I pointed you twice already to innodb's row level locking as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler construct:

```
db = connector.connect(...
cursor = db.cursor()
if cursor.execute('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE Id = 1 AND Total_Reg < 30'):
  print("REGISTERED!")   
else:
  print("CLOSED!")
db.close()
```

So:

- Don't use LOCK TABLES, not until you understand transactions, and then rarely
- Use the SQL to enforce the constraints you want
- Use the [return value](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#execute) to see if any rows where changed
- Don't use sleep statements

Comment: I got you, this function was just for testing that if in a case I've to execute more than one query at a time combined with python code like first selecting some data then having some operations to that data and then updating the database and all this just as a single query. I tried using transaction instead of TABLE LOCKS in above function but still while asyncio sleep starts running other instances running concurrently are still able to interfere between. I just want to know why is this happening? Is this a deadlock in above case? Just for my knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: Like, if in any case I've to use asyncio sleep within a transaction, how can I do so? As far as I tried different circumstances, above function is working fine in all conditions where asyncio sleep is not there, why so? Is MySQL not compatible with sleep statements or what?